# border-bottom spacing

Tags: html, css

I would like to have some spacing between `border-bottom`, as it is on second picture. if I add `padding-left`, only text and checkbox will move to right. `border-bottom` stays the same.

```
form td.caption {
 font-weight: bold;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
 padding-top: 1em;
}
```

My code gives me this:

> [image]

Style I want to achieve:

> [image: Style 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
table td.caption {
 font-weight: bold;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
 padding-top: 1em;
 min-width:100px;

}
table { 
    border-spacing: 10px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr><td class="caption">test</td><td class="caption">2</td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
table td.caption {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
   padding-top: 1em;
   width:150px;
   font-size:12px;
}
table { 
    border-spacing: 7px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
     <td class="caption">Select Chapters</td>
     <td class="caption" align="center"><input type="checkbox"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Is this the same that you are looking for?

Hope this helps.